# Add and show an error message with Phoenix.HTML.Form "With connection data"

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a simple form with a textarea, where the user will type in (or copy'n'paste) a json string into it. The form will be sent to my controller action and I will validate the json string and if it will be ok, I will create some records and all is fine.

To send the form to my controller action I use [Phoenix.HTML.Form](http://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Form.html) "With connection data" at the moment and therefore I have no model/changeset.

```
<%= form_for @conn, @action, [as: :match], fn f -> %>
  <%= textarea f, :json, rows: 20 %>
  <%#= error_tag @changeset, f, :json %>
<% end %>
```

If the json is invalid for some reason, I like to render the form again and display the error message(s). `error_tag` is a view helper method which will display an error at a field if there's a changeset. Because of this it's commented out now.

```
def error_tag(form, field) do
  if error = form.errors[field] do
    content_tag :span, (humanize(field) <> " " <> translate_error(error)), class: "help-block"
  end
end

def error_tag(changeset, form, field) do
  if changeset.action do
    error_tag(form, field)
  end
end
```

What is a proper way to add an error so that I can display them at a form field. Do I have to add the error to `@conn` or `f` (form) or Is there another way to got?

Comment: I think you could assign error(s) to your connection in the controller before rerendering the form and access those in the form since you pass connection to the template anyway.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I decided to implement a module that validates the json string. The module method `changeset` returns an `Ecto.Changeset` to which I added my custom errors. The private `validate_json` method checks the json schema and content. After all I set the changes and params to the given params from the form and I set valid? wether I have errors or not.

```
def changeset(required_fields, json_field, params) do
  changeset =
    %Ecto.Changeset{model: %MyApp.ModelName{}}
      |> Ecto.Changeset.cast(params, required_fields, ~w())
      |> validate_json(json_field, params)
  %Ecto.Changeset{changeset | changes: params, params: params, valid?: Enum.count(changeset.errors) == 0}
end
```

This way I keep my views and partials as they are and the form and all helper methods work with my changeset as they did before.

Answer (score 11):

### In your controller module

create a keyword list with the errors inside the action

```
errors = [field: "error message"]
```

then pass it when calling the [render](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.html#render/3) method

```
render(conn, "template.html", errors: errors)
```

### In your view module

add a helper function to extract and format the message from the keyword list

```
def error_tag(errors, field) when is_list(errors) and is_atom(field) do
  case Keyword.fetch(errors, field) do
    {:ok, message} -> content_tag :span, (humanize(field) <> " " <> translate_error(message)), class: "help-block"
    :error -> html_escape("")
  end
end
```

### In your template file

display the error message

```
<%= form_for @conn, @action, [as: :match], fn f -> %>
  <%= textarea f, :json, rows: 20 %>
  <%= error_tag @errors, :json %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried it out, but there were to many things I had to reimplement or extend. That produces ugly code. I tried a lot and after some experiments I decided to use an Ecto.Changeset as I did with a model.

Comment: Phoenix 1.2.3 `Phoenix.ErrorHelpers.translate_error({msg, opt})`, then `translate_error(msg)` will raise **no function clause matching in Phoenix.ErrorHelpers.translate_error/1**

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to create an `embeded_schema` in which you can define all the data model including validations without persisting into the DB, and rely on the validation/error management shipped in Phoenix. José Valim [explains](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2016/05/ectos-insert_all-and-schemaless-queries/) how to use this approach.

You just create the schema this way:

```
data  = %{}
types = %{first_name: :string, last_name: :string, email: :string}

changeset =
  {data, types} # The data+types tuple is equivalent to %Registration{}
  |> Ecto.Changeset.cast(params["sign_up"], Map.keys(types))
  |> validate_required(...)
  |> validate_length(...)
```

and then show the errors as usual:

```
<%= error_tag f, :first_name %>
```